# How do I do an LDAP query with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ldap

I'm trying to make a sidebar gadget that has an LDAP query function but haven't been able to find very good, or any, useful documentation on the matter. I'm not hugely experienced with Javascript and know little to nothing about how LDAP queries function, so any information at all would be useful.

info:

- host: a.b.c.d.e
- port: 389
- ou: people
- o: x_y_z
- c: us

first snippet:

```
var sSearchURL = "ldap://a.b.c.d.e:389/o=x_y_z,c=us";
var URLsuffix = "dc=" + form.SearchData.value;
document.location = sSearchURL URLsuffix;
```

other snippet:

```
var ldap = GetObject('LDAP:');
var ad = ldap.OpenDSObject(
  'LDAP://a.b.c.d.e:389/o=x_y_z',
  'cn=Administrator,ou=People,o=rootname',
  'password',
  0
);
```

Comment: the goal is to pull up information such as email, office #, phone # for a given name search. ie, search ted and get maybe 3 results, (ted jones, bill teddings, etc + all info regarding the searched individuals)

Comment: Maybe soon using WASM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you want to run your JavaScript in a web browser, you are limited to the HTTP protocol and to the domain from which your script was loaded in the first place.

So, talking to an LDAP server will not be possible from a web browsers JavaScript engine.

There are JavaScript runtime environments that have less limitations where you can implement socket servers and clients. For LDAP conenctivity you'd have to write your own library or find some existing one.

Comment: NB: a possible (but nasty) workaround is to use VBScript; only available in IE.  You could use this alone, or update the DOM via VBScript, then read data from the DOM using JS.  A better alternative would be to host a web service which gives you an API layer over LDAP.

Comment: "to the domain from which your script was loaded in the first place" would implicate that you would only be able to load scripts from one domain, which is not true?

Answer (score 5):

You could write a proxy web service that translates your HTTP requests into LDAP queries, forwards them to an LDAP server and returns the results back to you. Of course that'd have both security and scalability implications and is far from trivial.

Answer (score 3):

As Selfawaresoup already mentioned there are limitations to perfoming this on client side alone, however, if you're able to host your application/page on nodejs you can utilise an LDAP plugin with it.

Links to nodejs are as follows:
https://nodejs.org/en/
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Nodejs LDAP plugin:
http://ldapjs.org/

Instruction on setting up nodejs to serve http:
https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-simple-web-server-with-node-js/
https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/

Although it's for a specific application here's a manual demonstrating the integration of LDAP query via nodejs:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-use-ldap-authentication-authorization-node.js-bluemix-application/index.html

Here's a working demo of it (note this is for querying public facing LDAP servers):
https://login-using-ldap.mybluemix.net/

Best of luck to you however you resolve this.

Comment: Could you put in answer even short instruction or explanations? Just because URL sometimes doesn't live long.

Comment: If I get time I'll sit down and write something more verbose to assist, cheers.

Comment: outdated link...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure answer 1 is correct. Domain would be limited to client's domain for an *active directory* ldap query. However, LDAP://server is not limited to just local domain. Its limited to 'reachable' domains. If you can ping it you should be able to query it, given proper credentials.