# Querying local Active Directory from Blazor client side module?

Tags: c#, active-directory, blazor

I have existing .NET code that queries Active Directory once downloaded and running the .exe on a domain connected computer.

Could my .exe now run as a DDL in the Blazor browser (client-module) against the local domain and avoiding the downloading & running the .exe?

I know the sandboxed environment prevents native file system access, but would it prevent LDAP queries running?

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319249/how-do-i-do-an-ldap-query-with-javascript).

Blazor-in-the-Browser is held to the same limitations as JavaScript.
It's not a technical problem but a security issue.

You can of course use Blazor-on-the-Server, as long as that server has access to your AD.

Your users (on an intranet with good connections) won't notice the difference.