# query for an AD user with JS (in html page)

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I building an HTML page and in one of its text boxes I want the user to input the employee number and for it to be validated (whether the number is already in use or not) with a simple button.

The AD query itself is pretty simple and a single line in powershell can do it.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {employeenumber -eq "XXXXXXX"}
```

the problem starts (at least for me) in how to integrate this into the HTML page. I started reading in google but all the answers I found take me into PHP and JavaScript and really complex scripts (50+ lines of code) and since I have no knowledge in any of those languages, it becomes a tedious job for (what i assumed) a simple thing.

Is there a simple way to accomplished this (either  by writing a function in JS or by calling for an external PS script)? The HTML itself uses a simple `<table>` and some buttons that run very simple functions from a `.js` file located in the same folder (no IIS or other web servers are involved. Im running this locally for now).

Comment: How about using WinForms or WPF to build GUI applications natively with powershell?

Comment: @WasifHasan, thanks for the idea, this is actually pretty nice (and gave me all sorts of ideas for my other scripts) but my goal with this HTML page was to (ultimately) hand it to an HR employee to use. they cant be running code snippets or scripts. they need to have a closed piece of program that would do the function they need (or in this case, the function I want them to do)

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory works with the LDAP protocol and doesn't have a RESTful API by default.
It is impossible to send an LDAP request from the front-end side (I.E from the browser). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319249/how-do-i-do-an-ldap-query-with-javascript)

In many aspects (security, reliability, etc) the best way to do this would be to do this on the server side.

Comment: so is it possible to have an HTML button that will call for a powershell script on the server side and return the results to a label on the HTML page? if so, how do i do that?

Comment: It is possible, but I don't recommend it' as It all depends on the server side. 
I would focus on one server side language like ASP.NET or node.js, so that you won't have to be depended on Powershell.